# Как сделать автоматическое прокручивание ScrollView?

Tags: java, android

Есть кнопка,при нажатии на кнопку создается новый editText,когда экран становится заполненным вьюшками, нужно чтобы автоматически прокручивалось вниз до последней вью. 
Данный код не помогает:

```
 scrollViewPersonal.scrollBy(0,1000000000);
```

Как решить проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему с прокруткой ScrollView при добавлении нового элемента :

```
 scrollViewPersonal.post(new Runnable() {
                                               @Override
                                               public void run() {
                                                   scrollViewPersonal.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
                                               }

            });
```

В некоторых случаях вышеуказанный код может не работать, к сожалению причину не знаю. Чтобы все заработало,нужно использовать метод **postDelayed()**

```
scrollView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
    }
},1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Прокрутить ScrollView вниз можно так:

```
scrollViewPersonal.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
```

Добавьте этот код в метод обработки нажатия кнопки после создания нового View.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080402/android-scrollview-force-to-bottom

Comment: не работает)Она опускается вниз, но чтобы увидеть последнюю вьюшку нужно самому проскролить

Comment: т.е опускается до предпоследнего